# Changing my vote

Tags: feature-request, voting

I up-voted an answer from 0 to 1, but then thought better of it and tried the down button to undo it. But when I did, the score went from 1 to -1, which is not at all what I wanted.

Couldn't each member's contribution to the score change on the fly between -1, 0, and +1 by rolling up or down between them, recalculating its effect each time?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to undo your upvote then click on the up arrow to remove your vote. Clicking on the down arrow will remove your upvote then add a downvote.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. However, that seems really unintuitive to me. I assumed clicking up twice would be an attempt to add +2.

Comment: @JasonMelançon The tooltip on the arrows themselves say "click again to undo"

Comment: @JasonMelançon As you cannot vote up twice, it's reasonable for a repeat action to do something else. Think of it as a push-switch which you push to turn on and have to push again to turn off.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah, I get that. It's not unreasonable, just unintuitive. You're clicking up to go down.